# Create a Header and Sub-Header in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my desired output

[image]

However based on my code this is the current output

[image]

Here are my codes

```
 protected void grdVESONV_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "Header 4";
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);



            grdVESONV.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented by writing an event, `OnDataBound`  as `protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)` and use the `RowSpan` wherever is needed.

Comment: For more details refer, http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Merge-GridView-Cells-or-Columns-in-a-Row-in-ASPNet-using-C-VBNet.aspx

Comment: is that applicable to header?

Comment: You may have to tweak it further. Pl. follow the link, http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Merge-Merging-GridView-Header-Columns-Cells-by-adding-Multiple-Headers-Header-Row-in-ASPNET.aspx